# Getting position of Object3D after panning

Tags: three.js

This is probably something simple I'm overlooking. But I'm trying to get the position of an `Object3D` after panning. I'm using `OrbitControls`.

I've tried `object.position`, but the result returned is always the same. This is an example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/b9xxdubc/

I tried `grid.position`, but again, it always returned `(0, 0, 0)`, as I set it initially. I also tried setting an ID for the DOM element (`container`), and using jQuery's `position()` method, but no luck with that either.

So if I right click and pan around the grid, how can I get the new position of the grid on the screen (i.e., top, left)?

As always, many thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557341/three-js-get-world-rotation-from-matrixworld

Comment: @gaitat the linked question deals with getting the object's world rotation, I'm looking for object position on the screen. I don't believe these are duplicate questions.

Comment: look at the call `mesh.matrixWorld.decompose( position, quaternion, scale );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to do the trick, thanks to the answer of this question: [Converting 3D position to 2d screen position [r69!]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409074/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position-r69)

I just call this method whenever there is a change in controls (i.e., panning, rotating, etc.) to get the updated position.

```
function getScreenPosition(object, camera) {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

    var widthHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.width;
    var heightHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.height;

    object.updateMatrixWorld();
    vector.setFromMatrixPosition(object.matrixWorld);
    vector.project(camera);

    vector.x = (vector.x * widthHalf) + widthHalf;
    vector.y = -(vector.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;
    return vector;

}
```

Where `left` is `vector.x` and `top` is `vector.y`.

Comment: what if you want to get object top left? keeping in mind it might be rotated.